# Continuity of series implies continuity of coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Let the power series
>    $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(t)\,z^n $$
>   be holomorphic in $z$ and continuous in $t$ for every $z\in U\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $t\in [0,1]$, where $U$ is a non-empty open subset. 
>   Does it follow that the coefficients $a_n(t)$ are continuous for $t\in[0,1]$?

My stomach feeling is: "yes, absolutely!". Heuristically, we have a continuum infinite of continuous linear combinations, one for each $z\in U$, for countably many coefficients $a_n(t)$. This doesn't leave room for some of them not to be continuous.

To illustrate the idea, a recursive argument shows that if
$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n(t)z^n $$
is continuous for $n+1$ distinct (better algebraically independent to avoid pathologies) values of $z$: $z_0,...,z_n$, then the coefficients $a_n(t)$ are also forced to be continuous.

I'm grateful for any comment, proof or counterexample!

**Note**: This question has been heavily edited to avoid presenting two different issues in the same question. The previous version was phrased in terms of continuity almost everywhere, but I think this deflected the attention from the central point I'm addressing.

Comment: At least $a_0$ is continuous if $0$ is among the "almost every" ...

Comment: The only way I can think to prove it is by using integral formula. If it is $t$-continuous on the unit circle, then one can easily prove it. But since the unit circle has zero measure, it can be $t$-discontinuous at every point of the unit circle.

Comment: Try to show that the function is jointly continuous (actually uniformly continuous), in $t,z$ on $[0,1] \times D_1$, where $D_1$ is a closed disk containing $0$. Then use Cauchy's integral formula on a smaller disk $D_2$ to show that $a_n(t)$ are continuous functions.